# PHP session seen as local variable

Tags: php, session, session-storage

I have a problem with PHP session. When i start session, and try to add a variable to it i can only get in the same PHP script where i declared it like it's normal variable. Browser debuger also seems to not see any variable in session.

```
<?php

echo session_start(); //This returns 1 so session is created
$_SESSION["A"] = "B"; 
echo $_SESSION["A"]; // And this prints "B" as predicted 

?>
```

[But there is nothing in session!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z24pv.png)

Comment: Please print the session id to the browser and see it if continues to change every time you refresh the page. If it continues to change, it is possible the session file is not being created. Check your session folder to verity if the files are being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing server-side PHP sessions, with the client-side JavaScript `sessionStorage` here. Both are two completely different things.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

> Browser debuger also seems to not see any variable in session.

PHP session data is kept *on the server*, the browser can never “see it”, unless you explicitly output it somewhere (as you did with `echo $_SESSION["A"];`, but even then it of course won’t show in the sessionStorage debug panel.)

---

> i can only get in the same PHP script where i declared it like it's normal variable.

Then you most likely neglected to pick your session up again in the other script files. You need to call `session_start` at the beginning of *all* of them.

Comment: Ok, so that explain why i doesn't see session properties in browser debuger but shouldn't I be allowed to use this $_SESSION variables in different .php files? Beacause that's the main problem. I have a login form and i want to save logged user name in session to use it in different files but other scripts doesn't see it.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start` in _all_ those different scripts, or not?

Comment: Yes, that's how it looks:

In login.php:
`<?php
    session_start(); 
    #validation etc.
    $_SESSION["loggedUser"] = $firstName;
     header('Location: wall.php');
?>`

In wall.php:
`session_start();
        echo $_SESSION["loggedUser"];`

Comment: Have you checked what happens with the session id, as Sid adviced you to do with their comment above?

Comment: It's same in both views and it's stays same when I refresh the page.

Comment: This is not reproducible with what you have shown so far. You should start by verifying that `$firstName` actually contains what you think it should in the first script - if you are just writing an empty string or `false` into the session here, then trying to `echo` it will just show … nothing. Use `var_dump` instead of echo for debug outputs, that makes spotting what is actually going on easier, by also telling you the type and length of a variable.

Comment: Well, i fell dump. Yep, it  wasn't problem with session but with `$firstname`. Variable was empty and that's all. :| Thanks for help!